# TF model ValueError: Shapes (None, 2, 1) and (None, 4, 4) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have the shapes of training and testing data as following:

```
(9, 28, 28, 1), (3, 28, 28, 1), (9, 2, 1), (3, 2, 1)
```

the code as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras

from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.models import Sequential,Input,Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
batch_size = 28
epochs = 10
num_classes = 1
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same', input_shape=(9,784,1), 
activation='linear'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='linear',padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='linear',padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))


model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))


model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, 
optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs,verbose=1,validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

getting an error:

> ValueError: Shapes (None, 2, 1) and (None, 4, 4) are incompatible

Comment: your modelling mistake is there, you need to flatten the neurons ongoing to reach y shape

Comment: Always always state which line threw the traceback (was it the `model.add` line or `model.fit`?) Also, your title was very generic and this error could occur in many (non-TF) contexts. It helps to say it is TensorFlow.

Comment: model.fit line is getting error

Answer (score 0):

You have'nt mentioning proper `input shape` other than your data shape and assigning the end neurons `without flattening` the weights

Here i have added appropriately,

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.models import Sequential,Input,Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
batch_size = 28
epochs = 10
num_classes = 2
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same', input_shape=(28,28,1), 
activation='linear'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='linear',padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='linear',padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(12))
for layer in model.layers:
    print(layer.get_output_at(0).get_shape().as_list())
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))


model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, 
optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs,verbose=1)#,validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Out:

```
[None, 28, 28, 32]
[None, 14, 14, 32]
[None, 14, 14, 64]
[None, 7, 7, 64]
[None, 7, 7, 128]
[None, 4, 4, 128]
[None, 2048]
[None, 12]
Epoch 1/10
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 0.7242 - accuracy: 0.5556
Epoch 2/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7474 - accuracy: 0.4444
Epoch 3/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7997 - accuracy: 0.4444
Epoch 4/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.8712 - accuracy: 0.4444
Epoch 5/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.9182 - accuracy: 0.4444
Epoch 6/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.9220 - accuracy: 0.4444
Epoch 7/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.9011 - accuracy: 0.4444
Epoch 8/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.8745 - accuracy: 0.4444
Epoch 9/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.8506 - accuracy: 0.4444
Epoch 10/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 0.8342 - accuracy: 0.4444
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fcf40808050>
```

Comment: after running this i have got error in fitting the model

Comment: model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs,verbose=1)#,validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: would you mind showing the snippet @Issack